Axler's Measure Theory 3.34 Proof
I'm reading Sheldon Axler's Measure Theory book and have two questions about the proof of 3.34.


Here are my questions:

Why does
$$
\int_{[a, b]} (f^U - f^L) \, d\lambda = 0
$$
hold if and only if
$$
\left| \{ x \in [a, b] : f^U(x) \neq f^L(x) \} \right| = 0 \quad?
$$

What are the details of the last part "The remaining details ..."? How to finish the proof? I started with the following:
If $f$ is Riemann integrable, then by the first part, we have $\left| \{ x \in [a, b] : f^U(x) \neq f^L(x) \} \right| = 0$. Then by 3.38, we get
$$
\left| \{ x \in [a, b] : f \text{ is not continuous at } x \} \right| = 0.
$$
Then what should I do next to complete the proof?

Why is 3.38 true?


Thank you very much!
The images are from: Sheldon Axler. Measure, Integration & Real Analysis, Graduate Texts in Mathematics, Springer, 2020.

1, $f^U-f^L$ is non-negative. Recall that for a non-negative measurable function $\phi:E\to\mathbb R$ where $E$ is some measurable set of $\mathbb R$, $\int_E\phi=0\Leftrightarrow \phi(x)=0$ a.e. $x\in E$.
2, We claim: If $x_0\in [a,b]$ and when we partition $[a,b]$ into $2^n$ intervals, $x_0$ is not an endpoint for all $n$,
then $x_0\in \{x: f^U(x)\ne f^L(x)\}$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $f$ is discontinuous at $x_0$.
If we have shown this statement, then $\{x: f^U(x)\ne f^L(x)\}$ and the set of discontinuous points of $f$ only differ by an at most countable set (i.e. a subset of the set of the endpoints).
A fortiori they have the same Lebesgue measure.
To prove the claim it suffices to prove $x_0\in \{x: f^U(x)= f^L(x)\}$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $f$ is continuous at $x_0$.
If $f^U(x_0)=f^L(x_0)$, this would imply for all $\epsilon>0$, exists $N\in\mathbb Z_+$, $h_N(x_0)-g_N(x_0)<\epsilon$.
Or more explicitly, $\sup_{x\in I} f(x)-\inf_{x\in I}f(x)<\epsilon$,
where $I$ is one of the $2^N$ intervals obtained by partitioning $[a,b]$ equally, and the one which $x_0$ lies in.
By hypothesis $x_0$ is not the endpoint of $I$. Therefore we can select $\delta$, if $|x-x_0|<\delta$ then $x\in I$,
which implies $|f(x)-f(x_0)|<\epsilon$.
Therefore $f$ is continuous at $x_0$.
Conversely assume the continuity of $x_0$. For all $\epsilon>0$, exists $\delta$, if $|x-x_0|<\delta$ then $|f(x)-f(x_0)|<\epsilon$.
For large $n$ subject to $\frac{b-a}{2^n}<\frac{\delta}{100}$, if we partition $[a,b]$ into $2^n$ subintervals equally,
the interval $I$ containing $x_0$, which has length $\frac{b-a}{2^n}$, must lie in $\{x:|x-x_0|<\delta\}$.
Therefore $\sup_{x\in I}f(x)-\inf_{x\in I}f(x)<(f(x_0)+\epsilon)-(f(x_0)-\epsilon)<2\epsilon$,
i.e. $\lim_{n\to+\infty} h_n(x_0)-g_n(x_0)=0$, as desired.
3, Why $\lim_{n\to+\infty}\int_a^b h_n$ equals the Riemann integral of $f$:
By definition of Riemann sum, fr all $\epsilon>0$, exists $\delta>0$, if a partition of $[a,b]$ satisfies
the maximal length of the sub-intervals is less than $\delta$, then any Riemann sum $S$ of this partition satisfies
$$|\int_a^b f-S|<\epsilon.  $$
If $\frac{1}{2^N}<\delta$ and $n>N$, then, since $\int_a^b h_n$ can be viewed as a Riemann sum, the maximal length of the partitioned interval is $\frac{1}{2^n}$,
therefore $$|\int_a^b f-\int_a^b h_n|<\epsilon .\implies \lim_{n\to+\infty}\int_a^b h_n=\int_a^b f. $$

Thank you for your answer! Now I understand 1. For 2, are you trying to prove the part "Further more ..." in the theorem? I think by 3.38, everything before "Futher more ..." is proved.

@HelloVictor2000 What we desire to prove is: Let $f$ be bounded, then "the Riemann integral of $f$ exists" $\Leftrightarrow$ "discontinuous points of $f$" is of measure zero. In the textbook, the equation above the line "the remaining details..." claims that, Riemann integrable is equivalent to ${x:f^L(x)\ne f^U(x)}$ is of measure zero. In the part 2 of my answer I verified that ${x:f^L(x)\ne f^U(x)}$ and the set of discontinuous points differ by a set of measure zero, this completing the proof of equivalence of Riemann integrability and "discontinuous at a measure zero set".

As for why Riemann integral and Lebesgue integral coincide when the latter exists, i.e. the "Furthermore" part of the theorem, you may note that $\lim_{n\to+\infty}\int_{[a,b]}h_n$ is both the Riemann and Lebesgue integral of $f$ on $[a,b]$. This limit is the Lebesgue integral since step functions are also simple function. Why it also equals Riemann integral should be covered in the calculus course.

Oh ok, I see. So in part 2 of your answer you're proving that 3.38 is true, is that correct?

Yes, part 2 is proving 3.38 (or more precisely, they differ by a zero measure set).

Ok thank you! Now I understand everything before "Furthermore". But on proving if $f$ is Riemann integrable then $f$ is Lebesgue measurable, could you please include more details? I'm really confused. What I learned was that $f$ is Riemann integrable if its lower Riemann integral equals its upper Riemann integral, and then $\int_{a}^{b} f = L(f, [a,b]) = U(f, [a,b])$, where $L(f, [a,b]) = \sup_{P} L(f, P, [a,b])$ and $U(f, [a,b]) = \inf_{P} U(f, P, [a,b])$ taken over all partitions $P$. So did you get results on $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{[a,b]} h_n$ from these definitions?

Here is where I started with: If $f$ is Riemann integrable, then $\int_{a}^{b} = L(f, [a,b]) = U(f, [a,b]) = \int_{[a,b]} f^L d \lambda =  \int_{[a,b]} f^U d \lambda$. Should I continue from this?

@HelloVictor2000 I added this in my answer.

Ok, thank you very much!
